# Use htaccess to redirect root but still have directory listing accessible with a backdoor

Tags: .htaccess, directory-listing

What I thought I was trying to do was genius, but it seems to not work properly.

I have a public subdomain with temp files on it. I don't want people to be able to see all the files listed when they visit it. I don't want to password protect it because that will mess up several scripts when fetching files off the server, and I don't want a blank index.html there to stop listing because I want to be able to see the listing.

So my stroke of genius was to have a `.htaccess` file like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/#dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/?show=dir
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/ [nc]
```

My theory was that visiting `files.example.com` would redirect to `example.com` but visiting `files.example.com/?show=dir` or `files.example.com/#dir` would not; and obviously since `?show=dir` does nothing it would list all my files as normal.

My `RewriteConditions` have no effect though.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can't match against URL fragments (the `#dir` part) because that doesn't ever get sent to the server. It's a client side only thing.

Second, you can't match against the query string (the `?show=dir` part) in the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable, you need to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` instead.

So try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^show=dir$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/ [nc]
```

Comment: Ah you're amazing, thank you! That works perfectly. 

I knew I was taking my chances with #.